# Get DbDataReader without opening new connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following code works and fill my `DbDataReader` variable, but with opening a new connection:

```
var command = Db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "[dbo].[getPojistenecData]";

SqlParameter pa = new SqlParameter("@navInsureeNo", navInsureeNo);
SqlParameter vse = new SqlParameter("@all", all);

command.Parameters.Add(pa);
command.Parameters.Add(vse);

Db.Database.Connection.Open();
DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Is there a way how to fill `DbDataReader` without opening a new connection?

The following code also works, without opening new connection

```
Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC getPojistenecData @navInsureeNo, @all",
            new SqlParameter("@navInsureeNo", SqlDbType.VarChar) 
                { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = navInsureeNo },
            new SqlParameter("@all", SqlDbType.Bit) 
                { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = all})
           .AlignToInterface(pojistenec.ZastupceCompany);
```

Comment: An what is the purpose of "not opening a new connection" ? Can you explain further your question ?

Comment: I'm working on a project where I can't use it, it won't go through the interceptors

Comment: Main reason why am i doing it, this way is to obtain more results from stored procedure which DbDataReader allow me this

Comment: Do you have data in your application? if yes then you can using DataTable `table.CreateDataReader();` if no then how you will get data from database?

Comment: @Bobek What do you mean it won't go through interceptors ? Actually, you won't see it but in EF the method `Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` actually opens a connection because in general you always need a database connection to exchange with the database.

Comment: @Fourat opens it also, if there is opened connection?

Comment: @Bobek what do you mean ? Can you tell why you're not allowed to use `Context.Connection.Open()` ? What are the interceptors ?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is handling connections internally. EF opens connection executes query/stored procedure and closes the connection. so when your application executes `Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` EF will internally open connection.

If you have data in your application and don't want to fetch from database then you can use `DataTable.CreateDataReader()` get DataReader.

There is no way to get data from the database without opening a connection.

If your question is related to connection pooling, then all the drivers privde pooling functionality. if there is open idel connection then next time any one request to open connection ADO.NET will return already open idel connection.
it is true for both plain ADO.NET and EF.

Comment: i would try to use DataTable.CreateDataReader() method. Can you please provide me an example? How to call my store procedure you can see upper. but how to fill 2 classes?

Comment: you can not call stored procedure without opening connection.

Comment: how to obtain more results from database by calling Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand or something similar?